# In Verbindung mit welchen Verben kann der Infinitiv sowohl mit als auch ohne „zu“ stehen?

Tags: grammar, verb, infinitive

Auf [dieser Seite](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/verben/infinitiv) steht:

> In Verbindung mit den Verben *lernen*, *helfen* und *lehren* können wir den Infinitiv mit oder ohne *zu* verwenden.
>
> Beispiel:
> *Das Kind lernt laufen.*
> *Ich lerne, fehlerfrei zu schreiben.*
> …

Gibt es auch andere Verben, in Verbindung mit denen der Infinitiv sowohl mit als auch ohne *zu* stehen kann, oder sind es lediglich diese drei? Dazu kann ich keine weitere Quelle finden.

Comment: Auf jeden Fall _brauchen_, wobei da viele Sprecher die Konstruktion ohne _zu_ nicht akzeptieren („Wer brauchen ohne _zu_ gebraucht, braucht brauchen gar nicht zu gebrauchen“).

Comment: Beachte: "Ich helfe dir tragen", aber "Ich helfe dir das schwere Ding den Berg hoch **zu** tragen". Meinem Empfinden nach, ist im ersten Fall ein "zu" falsch, im zweiten Fall das Weglassen falsch. Die zitierte Aussage vermittelt aber den Eindruck, dass es nach Lust und Laune gesetzt oder weggelassen werden darf.

Comment: Eigentlich sollte das `zu` immer verwendet werden wenn die abgezielte Tätigkeit (Verb) an ein Adjektiv oder Nomen gebunden ist... Jedoch gibt es keine explizite Regelung wann sie wirklich gebunden sind. Deshalb wird es meist "gefühlt" gesprochen, weshalb deutsch so schwer ist :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ich denke, das Beispiel "brauchen" passt nicht ganz, für mein Empfinden ist das eine Unterscheidung in der Bedeutung zwischen "etwas brauchen" = "etwas benötigen" und "etwas zu tun brauchen" = "etwas tun müssen", also zwei vom Sinn her verschiedene Konstruktionen mit diesem Verb.

> "Ich brauche nicht zu arbeiten."

ist korrekt,

> "Ich brauche nicht arbeiten"

ist zumindest umgangssprachlich. Aber:

> "Ich brauche eine neue Hose"

ist korrekt, ich wüsste nicht, wo hier ein "zu" hinkönnte.

Mir fällt zumindest kein weiteres Verb ein, in dem, ohne den Sinn zu verändern, das zu gesetzt werden kann oder auch nicht. 
"Ich helfe dir zu tragen" ist für mich genauso korrekt wie "ich helfe dir tragen". Gleichfalls "ich helfe dir das Ding den Berg hochtragen".

Bei den drei Verben geht m.E. tatsächlich immer beides, wie "Ich helfe dir [zu] kochen", "Ich lerne [zu] rechnen", "Ich lehre meine Tochter [zu] reiten", also wirklich "nach Lust und Laune", was meiner Meinung nach bei anderen Verben nicht zutrifft, sondern dann mit einer anderen Grammatikkonstruktion bzw. anderem Sinn verbunden ist.
Beispiel: "Ich entschied mich, nach England aus**zu**wandern" vs. "Er entschied den Kampf in der letzten Minute", was ja ganz anderer Gebrauch des Verbs ist, so wie eben in "brauchen".

Comment: `"Ich brauche eine neue Hose"` ist leider ein unbrauchbares Beispiel: es wird auf eine Tätigkeit abgezielt... und außer du zeigst mir wie man "Hose" tun kann, ist es nicht für diesen Fall bestimmt...

Answer (score -1):

**Müssen** wäre ein weiteres solches Verb, ähnlich wie **brauchen**.

Wobei bei *müssen* ist das *zu* immer falsch ist. Zumindest fällt mir gerade wirklich kein Satz ein, wo man es hinzufügen könnte.

Bei *brauchen* hingegen ist das *zu* erwartet, aber zunehmend optional. Vermutlich wegen der ähnlichen Bedeutung wie *müssen*.

**Tun** klingt in diesem Zusammenhang zwar eher nach Kindersprache, aber auch hier würde das *zu* wegfallen.

Comment: Ich tippe, du wolltest optional schreiben? Ich hab's mal korrigiert ;)

Comment: Kannst du ein Beispiel mit "müssen" nennen, das zur Fragestellung passt? Hattest du so etwas wie "Er hat gehen müssen" im Kopf gehabt? Aber Sätze mit "zu müssen" sind gang und gäbe, es tut mir leid, das sagen zu müssen. Aber ein Beispiel mit dem Schema "Irgendwer lernt müssen" mag mir nicht in den Kopf kommen. Und "Irgendwer lernt tun" ist etwas, was nicht mal Kinder wirklich sagen, und  typische Verwendung von "tun" fallen imho auch nicht unter die Problematik in der Frage.

Comment: @Em1  Les mal nochmal die Frage. Es geht um Konstruktionen *wie* "Er lernt laufen", was bei anderen Verben eben mit "zu" gebildet werden müsste. Also, "Er lernt zu laufen". Bei "brauchen", "müssen" und "tun" ("Er muss gehen", "Sie braucht nicht (zu) warten") kann man das "zu" auch weglassen.

Comment: Ahhh... jetzt versteh ich deine Antwort. Ich hätte die Frage echt nochmal lesen sollen. Hatte sie anders in Erinnerung. :D Aber der Downvote ist nicht von mir.